# iPad: UISplitViewController top gets cut off inside UITabViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UITabViewController which contains a UISplitViewController as the first view.  When the app loads and shows the split controller, the top of the two views are cut off and shifted down a maybe 15 pixels. Clicking another tab fixes the problems and jumps both views back up:

When app loads:

[image: When app loads]

After clicking another tab problem is corrected:

[image: After fixed]

Code being used (unimportant stuff left out):

```
NewsSplit *newsTemp = [[NewsSplit alloc] init];
...
// The view controllers to the tabBar
[tabController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:newsSplit, eventSplit, classesSplit, dirSplit, settings, nil]];
...
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

**Why would the top be cut off and shifted down?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short of it is that `UISplitViewController` isn't supposed to be embedded within another view controller. It's meant to be the root view controller of your window. I've run into this exact same issue in the past. Support for things such as rotation was glitchy. I eventually got it working like I wanted, but it was a hassle.

Unless they've improved things, I think you're going to have to subclass some things and shift frames around to get it to look right.

Comment: Why does it fix itself when I click another tab that DOES have another UISplitViewController?

Comment: Not sure. I experienced this behavior as well. I had to manually adjust the frame to fix it for the first time.

Comment: Checking back on the project I had to do this with, I'm explicitly setting the frame of the view controller's view in `-viewWillAppear:` for whatever orientation the interface is in.

Comment: So this was in your splitviewcontroller? What did you set the frame to?

Comment: Apple's documentation explicity states that the split view controller should be the root of your hierarchy. It should not be nested in other view controllers.

Comment: Exactly. However, if you WANT it to force this to happen, you can. Just don't rely on it working in future versions of the SDK.

Comment: Hmmm.  Is there an alternate way to use a tabbarcontroller and splitviewcontroller are are they just not meant to work together?

Comment: They aren't meant to work together. However, it's really not that big of a deal to muck around with setting frames here and there to make it work. If you really want this use case, then you'll have to do a little digging around to get it working.

Comment: Ok, I have opted to use MGSplitViewController instead so I don't break Apple's rules.